# Writing a connection string to access a remote SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config, database-connection

My database is hosted on a remote server. I need to write the connection string which I have to include in the `web.config` file.

```
server name -- abcs.efgh.ed-1.eee.sss.com,1433 (it also contains a port as well)
username -- a
password -- a
db name -- mydb
```

I know how to connect to a local database and I use to refer to [connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012) for reference but, connecting to a remote database is a problem to me. Help please

**UPDATE**:

```
<connectionStrings>                                 
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="abcs.efgh.ed-1.eee.sss.com,1433;Integrated Security=True;User ID=a;Password=a" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Exception I get is :

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Actually, it's not Windows authentication that I want to use. It's SQL Server authentication which I want.

Comment: are you get any exception? show your current connection strings and update question with errors if any.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are encountering the error because you are using "integrated security=true" to connect. Use this website to construct your connection string. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/

I used the website to generate this connection string using your inputs:

```
Data Source=abcs.efgh.ed-1.eee.sss.com,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=a;Password=a
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `Integrated security =false.` in connection string

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When
>   true, the current Windows account credentials are used for
>   authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi
>   (strongly recommended), which is    equivalent to true. If User ID and
>   Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the
>   User ID   and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be
>   used. SqlCredential is a more secure way to specify credentials for a
>   connection that uses SQL Server Authentication (Integrated
>   Security=false).

More at [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)